# Python Pandas Passing a variable to merge

Tags: python, pandas

I don't know what I'm doing wrong with the `leftJoin()` function.
I have a connection to a DB2 database and an Oracle database.
Queries return me a result, both in DB2 and Oracle.
I continue to get the primary key value and try to pass it as a variable to the `leftJoin()` function, but it doesn't work here.
The key consists of two fields. If I manually put the value of `'ID', 'VER'` into on in `df1` in merge it works.

```
import ibm_db
import ibm_db as db
import ibm_db_dbi
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
import re


def connectDB2():
    arg1 = "DATABASE=...;HOSTNAME=...;PORT=...;UID=...;PWD=...;"
    conn = db.connect(arg1, "", "")
    if conn:
        print ('connection success')
        # Run SQL
        sql_generic = "SELECT distinct 'select ' || LISTAGG(COLNAME,', ') || '  from ' || trim(TABSCHEMA) || '.' || tabname || ' FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY' FROM SYSCAT.columns WHERE TABSCHEMA = '...' AND TABNAME = '...' AND COLNAME NOT IN ('CDC_STATUS','CDC_ODS_UPD') GROUP BY TABSCHEMA, TABNAME"
        stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, sql_generic)
        result = ibm_db.fetch_both(stmt)

        conn1 = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(conn)
        connectDB2.df = pd.read_sql(result['1'], conn1)

        print('df', connectDB2.df)


        sql_PK = "SELECT COLNAMES FROM syscat.INDEXES WHERE TABSCHEMA='...' AND TABNAME = '...' AND UNIQUERULE='P'"
        conn2 = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(conn)
        connectDB2.df1 = pd.read_sql(sql_PK, conn2)
        print('pk', connectDB2.df1)
        d = connectDB2.df1.loc[:, "COLNAMES"]
        print('d', d)
        print('d0', d[0])

        content_new1 = re.sub('$|^', '\'', d[0], flags=re.M)
        content_new2 = re.sub('\'\+', '\'', content_new1, flags=re.M)
        connectDB2.content_new3 = re.sub('\+', '\',\'', content_new2, flags=re.M)
        print('c3', connectDB2.content_new3)  --> format: 'ID','VER'
    else:
        print ('connection failed')

def connectOracle():
    con = cx_Oracle.connect('...')

    orders_sql = """select ...  from ... FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY""";

    connectOracle.df_orders = pd.read_sql(orders_sql, con)
    print(connectOracle.df_orders)

def leftJoin():
    df1 = pd.merge(connectOracle.df_orders, connectDB2.df, on=connectDB2.content_new3, how='left')

connectDB2()
connectOracle()
leftJoin()
```

I am adding below what the logs return.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\testConnection.py", line 68, in <module>
    leftJoin()
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\testConnection.py", line 57, in leftJoin
    df1 = pd.merge(connectOracle.df_orders, connectDB2.df, on=connectDB2.content_new3, how='left')
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 106, in merge
    op = _MergeOperation(
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 699, in __init__
    ) = self._get_merge_keys()
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1096, in _get_merge_keys
    right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1779, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: "'ID','VER'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the merge command wrongly,
I dont know what is actually inside your given dfs

```
connectOracle.df_orders
connectDB2.df
```

But i know for sure, you are doing a left join. And you are passing a key found on your second df or "right" df per say.

```
pd.merge(connectOracle.df_orders, connectDB2.df, on = 'guy with the same index found in both your dfs', how='left')
```

If you dont have that guy, well them you should define your left key or your right  that want to 'join', on the  parameters